# WPF DataGrid - Notify another class of user selected value

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have been trying this for a few days now. I am new to coding and quite new to WPF and DataGrids. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkoUX.jpg) of the datagrid

Basically the datagrid on the left has a different ItemSource  to the one on the right.

In the right datagrid, the user selects the brand for which he wants to calculate the total amount. I capture the selected row and get the brand rate as follows -

```
        private void BrandGrid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<DataGridCellInfo> info = BrandGrid.SelectedCells.ToList();
        rate = 0;
        if (info.Count > 0)
        {
            Brand i = (Brand)info[1].Item;
            rate = i.Rate;
        }
    }
```

Now how do I tell the other class to use the selected rate to calculate the total amount. In the same fashion as I calculate the total area

> TotalArea = length * quantity * someConstantWidth (this one was easy using INotifyPropertyChanged). When the user edited the length and quantity in the datagrid, the TotalArea would update simultaneously.
>
> Whereas here TotalAmount = TotalArea * *SelectedRate* has gotten me quite confused as to how to send the information from the MainWindow.BrandGrid_SelectedCellsChanged to another class.

I have tried poking around with delegate and events unsuccessfully cause in my example application I'm finding it difficult on how to implement it.

What is the best method? How do I go on about this?

**UPDATE**
Thanks you so much for such a detailed response! I have few more doubts regarding the implementation ,

(1) In step 1 the line of code: public void SelectBrand() => OnBrandSelect?.Invoke(this, Rate);
I assume here Rate is the variable name and not the type? My variable Rate is a double type.

(2) To address your note on the Result Class: The length and quantity are user inputs - using which Total Area is calculated. Here Length, Quantity, Area etc are within the same class Result and I use INotifyPropertyChanged to update the TotalArea column.

(3) In your example for Result Class, it requires me to create the ResultObject with a Brand Type input. Any other way? As user should be able to include all the length and quantities of an order placed by a customer and then select the brand later.

I would like the output to be similar to how INotifyPropertyChanged handles changes. It changes the cells real time as I am changing the inputs in the other cells - similar behavior if possible would be awesome.

**UPDATE 2**
B.Spangenberg, you have given an excellent solution. I tried your code and added a button to add items and the code works perfectly but I guess I had some requirements missing from my question.

The DataGrid I have is "IsEnabled" and allows a new row to be added - once the present row is added, the new row automatically appears which can be edited.

By understanding your solution, here are the proper requirements -
(1) No button to add items to the OrderGrid. New row appears automatically.

(2) The brand can be selected first before entering the items or after entering the items.

(3) Once the user selects a brand ALL the items' TotalAmount are updated. There is NO *selection* of an item in the OrderGrid.

(4) If the user adds a new item in the OrderGrid after selecting a brand, the new item's TotalAmount is calculated based on the brand that is already presently selected.

*Note:* You are right about "SelectedCellsChanged" I have changed that to a MouseDoubleClick event. It's now very reliable and also a better feel for the user. THANK YOU!

Comment: You mentioned that you're trying to send data from MainWindow.BrandGrid_SelectedCellsChanged to another class. I might not completely understand the issue here, but generally this is done by instantiating the class and passing the values via the constructor. 

If the class is purely for calculations, you could make it static and just call the required methods from the class. Passing the data directly to the methods.

Comment: Oh, I think I get what you're after now. I'll create and post an answer for you shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I assume you're trying to invoke an event from your selected brand to convey to anyone listing that the brand rate is (), which is then used to calculate the Total.

**Step 1:**
You'll need to add an event to your "Brand" class and create a public method to invoke it internally.

```
class Brand
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Rate Rate { get; set; }

    public void SelectBrand() => OnBrandSelect?.Invoke(this, Rate);

    public event EventHandler<Rate> OnBrandSelect;
}
```

**Step 2:**
Hook your brand events when you load them into the collection that contains them which is used as the grid source. Basic example below.

```
// load brands from db or elswhere.
List<Brand> brandsSelectedToLoad = new List<Brand>()

 ObservableCollection<Brand> BrandDisplayCollectionToBeUsedAsGridSource = new ObservableCollection<Brand>();
 foreach (Brand brand in brandsSelectedToLoad)
 {
      brand.OnBrandSelect += (s, args) => { /* Call calculation method (TotalAmount = TotalArea * args -- args is rate) and set the result */}
      BrandDisplayCollectionToBeUsedAsGridSource.Add(brand);
 }
```

**Step 3:**
Then, when you select your brand from the grid, you invoke the brand event. Any listeners should then do their jobs.

```
private void BrandGrid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
{
     List<DataGridCellInfo> info = BrandGrid.SelectedCells.ToList();
     if (info.Count > 0)
     {
         Brand selectedBrand = info[1].Item as Brand;
         if (selectedBrand == null)
             return;

         selectedBrand.SelectBrand();
     }
}
```

*NOTE :* 
The other grid which I'll refer to as the "Result Grid" will most likely need to reflect these calculations based on rate invoked by the event, within the Total Amount column. 
I assume these items in your "Result Grid" are actual result objects,
but I don't see any clear relation between the result record and the
selected brand. (unless it's hidden within the result object). Which
leaves me to believe that you just add the record to the Result Grid on brand select and forget it.

You will need to embed the same Brand object reference that you load into you Brands Grid into your result object and hook it's event inside of the result object. (Almost the same as in step step two). You can ignore step two then and use the below.

**Example :**

```
class Result : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double total;

    public Result(Brand brandRef)
    {         
        this.Brand = brandRef;
        brand.OnBrandSelect += (s, args) => 
            { 
               /* Call calculation method (TotalAmount = TotalArea * 
                  args -- args is rate) and set the result */

               Total = /*(TotalAmount = TotalArea * 
                  args -- args is rate)*/;
            }
    }

    public double Total   
    {
        get { return total; }
        set
        {
            total = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**Update Response**

The rate object can be replace by your double type. Just swap all "Rate" with double.

I see. So the brand selection is only available after the user has configured the length and quantity inputs. Therefore having the brand parameter within the construct is not possible, cause you need your result object instantiated beforehand.

Do the following :

1) Create brand object as I have it in step one. Just replace the Rate with double.

2) Add a method called "Calculate(double rate)" to your result object which takes double. Within this method you run you calculation for total and set the total property.

```
public void Caculate(double rate)
{
    TotalAmount = TotalArea * rate;
}
```

3) So now you need some way to keep you event subscribed to the selected grid row on the result grid. So each time you add a result object into your grid source collection, you will need to hook each brand object event to it.

So I assume somewhere you have a button that adds a new record to the result grid to be configured by the user and then he selects the brand. Just before the point where you add the object to the result object collect. Hook it with the following.

```
ResultObject resultObj = new ResultObject()
BrandCollection.All(brand => 
{ 
   brand.OnBrandSelect += (s, rate) => 
   { 
      resultObj.Calculate(rate);
   }; return true; 
});
resultGridCollection.Add(resultObj);
```

So now each brand object has a hooked function that calculates and sets the existing result object on select. You still use Step 3 to invoke the selection event.

Keep in mind you will need to unsubscribe all brand events every time you add a new object, otherwise the brand selection will keep altering all your results. If you want to support changes on selected GridResult instead, you just need to move the subscription code to from the add method to the selected grid cell method for result.

I hope this all makes sense.

**Update 2**

I decided to go the extra mile for you. Here is the code you need. All of it.

```
namespace GridSelection
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
   /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        MainWindowViewModel model = new MainWindowViewModel();
        public MainWindow()
        {
           InitializeComponent();
           OrdersGrid.SelectedCellsChanged += OrdersGrid_SelectedCellsChanged;
           BrandGrid.SelectedCellsChanged += BrandGrid_SelectedCellsChanged;
           this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
     }


    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        model.Load();
        this.DataContext = model;
    }

    private void OrdersGrid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid grid = sender as DataGrid;
        Order selectedOrder = grid.SelectedItem as Order;

        if (selectedOrder == null)
            return;

        model.BrandCollection.All(b => 
        {
            b.UnsubscribeAll();
            b.OnBrandSelect += (s, rate) => 
            {
                selectedOrder.CalculateTotal(rate);
            }; return true;
        });
    }

    private void BrandGrid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid grid = sender as DataGrid;
        Brand selectedbrand = grid.SelectedItem as Brand;

        if (selectedbrand == null)
            return;

        selectedbrand.InvokeBrandSelected();
    }
}

internal class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Brand> BrandCollection { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Order> OrderCollection { get; private set; }
    public ICommand AddNewOrderCommand { get; private set; }

    public void Load()
    {
        BrandCollection = new ObservableCollection<Brand>
        {
            new Brand() { Name = "Brand One", Rate = 20 },
            new Brand() { Name = "Brand Two", Rate = 30 },
            new Brand() { Name = "Brand Three", Rate = 50 }
        };

          OrderCollection = new ObservableCollection<Order>();

          AddNewOrderCommand = new CustomCommand(p => 
          {
              OrderCollection.Add(new Order());
          });
      }
  }

  public class Order : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    #region Private Variables
      private int length;
      private int quantity;
      private int totalArea;
      private double totalAmount;
     #endregion

      #region Public Properties
      public int Length
      {
           get { return length; }
           set
           {
               length = value;
               NotifyPropertyChanged();

               CalculateArea();
           }
       }

        public int Quantity
        {
            get { return quantity; }
            set
            {
                quantity = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();

                CalculateArea();
            }
        }

        public int TotalArea
        {
            get { return totalArea; }
            set
            {
                totalArea = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public double TotalAmount
        {
            get { return totalAmount; }
            set
           {
               totalAmount = value;
               NotifyPropertyChanged();
           }
        }

        #endregion

        private void CalculateArea()
        {
            TotalArea = this.Length * this.Quantity;
        }
        public void CalculateTotal(double rate)
        {
            TotalAmount = this.TotalArea * rate;
        }

        #region Public Methods
        public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion

        #region Events
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        #endregion
    }

    public class Brand
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Rate { get; set; }

        public void InvokeBrandSelected() => OnBrandSelect?.Invoke(this, Rate);
        public void UnsubscribeAll() => OnBrandSelect = null;

        public event EventHandler<double> OnBrandSelect;
    }

    // Interface 
    public interface ICustomCommand : ICommand
    {
        event EventHandler<object> Executed;
    }

    // Command Class
    public class CustomCommand : ICustomCommand
    {
        #region Private Fields
        private readonly Action<object> _execute;
        private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public CustomCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null)
        {
        }

        public CustomCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute)
        {
            _execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
        _canExecute = canExecute ?? (x => true);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public Methods
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter = null)
        {
            Refresh();
            _execute(parameter);
            Executed?.Invoke(this, parameter);
            Refresh();
        }

        public void Refresh()
        {
            CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Events
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            }
            remove
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
            }
        }
        public event EventHandler<object> Executed;
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Just to note, I noticed that the on grid select is not very reliable. You will just need to look into that.It seems when the grid gains focus and is first selected, that does not fire the SelectedCellsChanged.

**UPDATE**

Here is the code based on the update you posted.

```
namespace GridSelection
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
       MainWindowViewModel model = new MainWindowViewModel();
       public MainWindow()
       {
           InitializeComponent();

           BrandGrid.MouseDoubleClick += BrandGrid_MouseDown;
           OrdersGrid.InitializingNewItem += OrdersGrid_InitializingNewItem; ;

           this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
       }

    private void OrdersGrid_InitializingNewItem(object sender, InitializingNewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Order newOrder = e.NewItem as Order;
        if (newOrder == null)
            return;

        if(model.CurrentBrand != null)
        {
            newOrder.UpdateRate(model.CurrentBrand.Rate);
        }

        model.BrandCollection.All(b =>
        {
            b.OnBrandSelect += (s, rate) =>
            {
                newOrder.UpdateRate(model.CurrentBrand.Rate);
                newOrder.CalculateTotal();
            }; return true;
        });
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        model.Load();
        this.DataContext = model;
    }

    private void BrandGrid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid grid = sender as DataGrid;
        Brand selectedbrand = grid.SelectedItem as Brand;

        if (selectedbrand == null)
            return;

        selectedbrand.InvokeBrandSelected();
    }
}

   internal class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       private Brand currentBrand;

       public ObservableCollection<Brand> BrandCollection { get; private set; }
       public ObservableCollection<Order> OrderCollection { get; private set; }

       public Brand CurrentBrand
       {
           get { return currentBrand; }
           set
           {
               currentBrand = value;
               NotifyPropertyChanged();
           }
       }

       public void Load()
       {
           BrandCollection = new ObservableCollection<Brand>
           {
              new Brand() { Name = "Brand One", Rate = 20 },
              new Brand() { Name = "Brand Two", Rate = 30 },
              new Brand() { Name = "Brand Three", Rate = 50 }
           };

           OrderCollection = new ObservableCollection<Order>();
       }

       public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
       {
           PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
       }

       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   }

   public class Order : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
      #region Private Variables
      private int length;
      private int quantity;
      private int totalArea;
      private double totalAmount;
      #endregion

      public Order()
      {

      }

       #region Properties
       private double Rate { get; private set; }
       public int Length
       {
         get { return length; }
         set
          {
               length = value;
               NotifyPropertyChanged();

               CalculateArea();
               CalculateTotal();
           }
       }
       public int Quantity
       {
           get { return quantity; }
           set
           {
               quantity = value;
               NotifyPropertyChanged();

               CalculateArea();
               CalculateTotal();
           }
       }
       public int TotalArea
       {
           get { return totalArea; }
           set
           {
               totalArea = value;
               NotifyPropertyChanged();
           }
       }
       public double TotalAmount
       {
           get { return totalAmount; }
           set
           {
               totalAmount = value;
               NotifyPropertyChanged();
           }
       }
       #endregion

       #region Methods
       private void CalculateArea()
       {
           TotalArea = this.Length * this.Quantity;
       }

       public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
       {
           PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
       }
       public void CalculateTotal()
       {
           TotalAmount = this.TotalArea * this.Rate;
       }
       public void UpdateRate(double rate)
       {
           Rate = rate;
       }
       #endregion

       #region Events
       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
       #endregion
   }

   public class Brand
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public double Rate { get; set; }

       public void InvokeBrandSelected() => OnBrandSelect?.Invoke(this, Rate);
       public void UnsubscribeAll() => OnBrandSelect = null;

       public event EventHandler<double> OnBrandSelect;
   }
}
```

Comment: I have few more doubts regarding the implementation -

Comment: Please explain. I'll see how I can help.

Comment: Just updated on the main question post. Had no idea about comment time limit thing.

Comment: Added my response, I believe that solution will work for you. If you're having trouble with implementation, let me know.

Comment: I re-created and tested the app on my side. I added all the code you need. Good luck. Just read the note I left at the end.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Actually I don't have anything that adds a new item in my OrderGrid. The DataGrid is IsEnabled, so once I fill in a particular row, the next row automaticall appears. Also, I don't want the user to select an "item" in the OrderGrid, once the Brand is selected - all the items in the OrderGrid are re-calculated for that brand. And if a new item is added, it is calculated based on the brand that is already selected. The user of this app can either fill out all the items in the OrderGrid and then select the brand or select the brand first then fill out the items.

Comment: Updated my main post with better explanation of my requirements. And thanks for your note on SelectedCellsChanged.

Answer (score 0):

Writing this for anyone who might expect a different behavior with INotifyPropertyChanged.

I noticed that real-time value change cannot be triggered with -

```
public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
{
   PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

**By real-time** I mean - as you are changing a value in datagrid, another value in a different column, same row changes simultaneously. Whereas in the above code, you need to click on the cell for the value to update.

The best way for this neat behavior is -

```
public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
{
   PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

And call this method as NotifyPropertyChanged(yourVariableName);